# Reuse custom color with custom name

Tags: dart, flutter

In Android I could do this in my `colors.xml`:

```
<color name="my_custom_blue">#F7DC16</color>
```

In Flutter the only way to reuse colors is to define them in the Theme. However I want to define my custom colors with custom names so I can use it like this:

```
color: Colors.myCustomBlue
```

Anybody know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
color: MyColors.myCustomBlue
```

there is no way to extend the static members of `Colors` with your custom entries. You can include all `Colors` entries in your `MyColors` so you don't have to use multiple names.

You can even name your own set `Colors`, you just have to be careful to not import both at the same time (the IDE will warn about conflicts)

```
import 'package:my_package/colors.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' hide Colors;
```

Comment: very nice, how to include the entries from colors in my custom class? Sorry, really new to dart and flutter.

Comment: You can either just manually copy the source from the original `Colors` class, or reference them like `class /*My*/ Colors { static const Color black = material.Colors.black; ... }`. If you use `import 'package:flutter/material.dart' as material;` to avoid the naming conflict.

Comment: Do you know why you can not set ThemeData(primarySwatch:MyColors.myCustomBlue) ?

Comment: @AlexandraDamaschin I'd suggest to create a new question with more details.

Answer (score 12):

I would suggest you create your own custom colors in another file:

```
class Colors {
  static const Color myCustomBlack = const Color(0x8A000000);
  static const Color white = const Color(0xFFFFFFFF);
}
```

but if you want to use them in your project,
**with CupertinoColors there is no conflict** but with material **Colors**, you should either change the class name to something like MyColors which I think is better or you can hide the Colors class from the Material Library.
if you want to use them just import the dart file and you are good to go.